# json deserializing

Tags: java, json

Just starting so any facilitation appreciated.
Have an object serialized it to this starting segment:

> [{"boo00":true,"lineItem":[{"bool00":true,"display":false,"extra00":"objectType","status":"","value":"recordType:A"},
>   {"bool00":true,"display":false,"extra00":"0","status":"","value":"UPC:1"},{...},{...}],"rowId":0,"str00":"hidden"},

The object has four elements: `boo00` (boolean), `lineIem` (ArrayList), `rowID` (int), `str00` (String)

I have this segment where I am trying to understand how to build back my object

```
String flatten = lines.toString();
JSONObject outer = JSONObject.fromObject(flatten);
Iterator itr04 = null;
for(itr04 = outer.entrySet().iterator(); itr04.hasNext();){
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) itr04.next();
    String key = (String)entry.getKey();
    System.out.println("key= "+key);
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

> "net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of []"

which at this point makes little sense to me because that is exactly how it starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON text begins with a square bracket: `[`, not a curly brace: `{`. The JSON string represents an *array* of objects.

Your `outer` should be a [`JSONArray`](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html).

Comment: Thank you.If I can follow up here goes.  How to I get the next "chunk"?  JSONArray.size() shows three elements of my object type.  Now since I know the structure how to I parse recursively into each?  In this case where I have one object that contains some primitives and an ArrayList, how do get that as a separated chunk and parse that and iterate the list within?

Comment: @cp - If you know you have a JSONArray, you can iterate through it and extract each element.  If you *know* that every element will be a JSONObject then you can just cast to that.  If you're not sure, use `instanceof` to test the type of the array element before casting.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Java JSON stuff is sort of brain dead, one thing you can do is concatenate "[" and "]" to the front and end of the string.  Then you can always use JSONArray to read the string, and then do `instanceof` on each array element to find out what you have.